# Why does changing directory in a bash session launched from a git rebase exec make it look like my entire repo is different?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a git repo with no changes made to any of the previously pushed code. I do git rebase -i and enter the following:

```
x bash
noop
```

I save this and it drops me (as expected) into a brand new bash shell. Now I look at what's changed in one of the directories in the repo. It doesn't seem to matter which directory, and the directories are just plain directories - not submodules or symlinks.

```
 > git diff dpdb/ | wc -l
0
```

As expected - no diffs. So far, so good.

Now I change directory to the directory with no diffs and ask the same question:

```
 > cd dpdb
 > git diff . | wc -l
3646276
 >
```

Now it looks like the entire universe has changed. If I do git status it appears like almost everything has been removed:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto f6eb027d2
Last command done (1 command done):
   exec bash
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   noop
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'f6eb027d2'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    deleted:    .gitmodules
    modified:   Makefile
    modified:   README.md
<snip several hundreds more lines more>
```

If I actually dig into it it looks like it's trying to compare the directory I just changed to against the top-level directory - which is why files like Makefile, .gitignore and README.md appear as modified rather than deleted - because I have README files in both directories (different files of course, but with the same name).

What I don't understand is why this is happening or how I get it to resume its normal behavior.

Environment variables (taken during the rebase op itself):

```
GIT_INTERNAL_GETTEXT_SH_SCHEME=gnu
GIT_DIR=/home/richard/cc/.git
GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP=
GIT_REFLOG_ACTION=rebase -i (start): checkout refs/remotes/origin/master
GIT_PREFIX=
GIT_PAGER=cat
```

Of these, only GIT_PAGER is set normally. Git version is 2.17.5.

Comment: Isn't `git diff directory` only reporting for that single directory, whereas `.` means this directory and all subdirectories, recursively?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, it reports all changes in that directory.

Comment: OK, well remove the `| wc -l` part then to see exactly which changes are being reported, this might tell you why it is or isn't being included.

Comment: is `dpdb` a simple directory, or a submodule ? what does `git status` (or the more compact `git status -s`) say in both locations ?

Comment: Simple dir - I've tweaked the question to address the above.

Comment: That's ... odd, and I can't reproduce it in the Git version I just tried. What version of Git are you using? I have a thought or two about what might be going on, so one more question: in this odd state, what does `env | grep GIT` show?

Comment: You probably have many GIT* environment variables defined in that subshell, and that distorts the ways git works. For breaking out from the rebase is better to use `x false` which you can then "skip"

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - especially the x false trick. That works and doesn't suffer the same problem. I've updated the question with the other info.

Comment: @max630 Turn the comment into an answer and I'll accept.